# @ oracle equivalent in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

How can i run multiple sql files from one main sql files in postgres.

For example in oracle
Inside Main.sql i can specify n number of @Child.sql , and then i can run Main.sql to run all child.sql 's .

How can i do this in the postgres.

Thanks!
Pratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\i` is the `psql` equivalent of the Oracle SQL*Plus @ command.

If you're using psql to run the Main.sql script, you can put:

```
\i path/to/child.sql
```

... in Main.sql. The difference between this and the `EXECUTE SCRIPT` command pointed out by Tzury is that there the path in `FILENAME` would refer to a path on the server's file system, while the `\i` command refers to a path on the machine running `psql`.